# Google API Calendar v3 Token Authentication only once

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have searched for days, but I can't get my answer, so I create this post.

I developed a web app, so the user can create event in their Google Calendar. It is working. But, I can't figure, why this app only asks the user credential once.

**For example:**

> 1. User John access the .aspx page then he redirected to Google Authorized page because it's the first time John access the page.
> 2. After Authorized, John can create an event in his Google Calendar.

It works until this step. The problem occurred when John logout from his google account.

> 3. If Dave accesses this page from another computer, he's not redirected to Google Authorized page and suddenly directly creates an event in
>      JOHN's Calendar.

Can someone help me, why this problem occurred?

**this is my code:**

```
Protected Sub new_authentication()
    Dim datafolder As String = Server.MapPath("App_Data/CalendarService.api.auth.store")
    Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim UserId As String = "GoogleID_co"

    scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
    Dim myclientsecret As New ClientSecrets() With { _
      .ClientId = myClientID, _
      .ClientSecret = ClientSecret _
    }

    Dim flow As GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

    flow = New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer() With { _
      .DataStore = New FileDataStore(datafolder), _
      .ClientSecrets = myclientsecret, _
      .Scopes = scopes _
    })

    Dim uri As String = Request.Url.ToString()

    Dim code = Request("code")
    If code IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(UserId, code, uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?")), CancellationToken.None).Result

        ' Extract the right state.
        Dim oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(flow.DataStore, UserId, Request("state")).Result
        Response.Redirect(oauthState)
    Else
        Dim result = New AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, uri, uri).AuthorizeAsync(UserId, CancellationToken.None).Result
        If result.RedirectUri IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Redirect the user to the authorization server.
            Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri)
        Else
            ' The data store contains the user credential, so the user has been already authenticated.
            myCalendarservice = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
              .ApplicationName = "My Calendar", _
              .HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential _
            })

            createcalendar()


        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**This is my createcalendar sub**

```
Protected Sub createcalendar()
   Dim newEvent As New [Event]() With { _
       .Summary = "Google I/O 2015", _
       .Location = "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103", _
       .Description = "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.", _
       .Start = New EventDateTime() With { _
           .DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2015-07-13T09:00:00-07:00"), _
           .TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles" _
       }, _
       .[End] = New EventDateTime() With { _
           .DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2015-07-14T17:00:00-07:00"), _
           .TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles" _
       }, _
       .Recurrence = New [String]() {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"}, _
       .Attendees = New EventAttendee() {New EventAttendee() With { _
           .Email = "lpage@example.com" _
       }, New EventAttendee() With { _
           .Email = "sbrin@example.com" _
       }}, _
       .Reminders = New [Event].RemindersData() With { _
           .UseDefault = False, _
           .[Overrides] = New EventReminder() {New EventReminder() With { _
               .Method = "email", _
               .Minutes = 24 * 60 _
           }, New EventReminder() With { _
               .Method = "sms", _
               .Minutes = 10 _
           }} _
       } _
   }

    Dim calendarId As [String] = "primary"
    Dim request As EventsResource.InsertRequest = myCalendarservice.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId)
    Dim createdEvent As [Event] = request.Execute()
End Sub
```

Comment: what value did you pass to  Dim code = Request("code") to code here? Are you storing token of John here? Also, to understand oauth flow, check this oauth play ground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ where you can see how authorization and authentication is done.

Comment: code is parameter if you're redirected back from Google page authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I found that the name of token always same that's why this problem occurred. So, just replace this code:

```
Dim datafolder As String = Server.MapPath("App_Data/CalendarService.api.auth.store")
Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
Dim UserId As String = "GoogleID_co"
```

into

```
Dim datafolder As String = Server.MapPath("App_Data/CalendarService.api.auth.store")
Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
Dim UserId As String = "GoogleID_co" & {unique Identifier such as userid,username,etc}
```